# Remove duplicate elements from the DOM

Tags: jquery, html, css

Want to remove the duplicated elements with the same classname(valid) from the DOM. Below is the example:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="test1">
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
</div>  
<div class="test2">
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Expected is:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="test1">
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
</div>  
<div class="test2">
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all elements except the first one using [`:nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) pseudo-class selector and then remove them.

```js
$('.valid:nth-child(n+2)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<div class="test1">
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
</div>  
<div class="test2">
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
</div>
</div>
```

---

Or using combination of [`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo-class selectors.

```js
$('.valid:not(:first-child)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<div class="test1">
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
</div>  
<div class="test2">
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
</div>
</div>
```

---

**FYI :** To hide the elements initially, you can use following css.

```
.valid:nth-child(n+2){
   display : none;
}
```

---

Without using jQuery library.

```js
// get all duplicate element and convert nodelinst into array
// use [].slice.call in older browser to convert in to an array
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.valid:nth-child(n+2)'))
  // iterate over elements 
  .forEach(function(ele) {
    // remove element from its parent
    ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
  });
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="test1">
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="valid">&nbsp;</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Pranav,Thanks for the reply. It works! One small issue is those duplicated elements are displaying some fraction of seconds while loading the page. Is there a way to not appear that also.

Comment: @user3774781 :  add following style on header `.valid:nth-child(n+2){ display : none; }`

Comment: @Wei-jye : yes using js, added in answer

Comment: @PranavCBalan nice one.